# How to remove 'pafy' after installing it using sudo pip install from ubuntu 18.04 running python 3.6?

Tags: python, opencv, pafy

I installed the pafy's package as super user, but I run python as normal user. So I can't actually use the module. How can I remove it in order to re-install using pip install as normal user? thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you install it with super user privs? If you installed it with `pip`, you could just do `sudo pip uninstall pafy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removal:

If you installed `pafy` using `sudo pip` or `sudo python -m pip`:

```
sudo pip uninstall pafy
# OR
sudo python -m pip uninstall pafy
```

If you installed `python-pafy` using another package manager (e.g. `apt-get`, you'll need to remove it using that package manager (`sudo apt-get remove python-pafy`)

Re-installation:

```
python -m pip install --user pafy
```